# How does MySql database handles multiple update operation

Tags: mysql, concurrency

I am new to database and the way they work so my question might be a bit dumb, **please be nice.**

I have always been thinking about how database update work in general and I think I understand the process kind of, but my real curiosity is that how does database engines in general handle update to an existing record from multiple threads?

To be clear, let say your mysql database got 10 queries at the same time to update a particular same field, how is this operation handled?
From my point of view, If the database got updated at the same time maybe by the help of multi threading, then the data on that field might not be accurate.

Another thing that came to my mind is Synchronization, coming from java point of view, I am thinking the database will queue the request and make sure one operation finishes before another.

I need clarity on this, any help and I will be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In MySQL innodb [MVCC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html) is one way. Multiple updates to the same row could also dead-lock for the application to handle.

Comment: See "Transactions" and the "A" in "ACID".

Comment: at the exact same time is dang near impossible - one of the update statements change the value - and depending on the where condition the others might entirely fail (if the check for the old value of said column) - or change if after the write lock is gone. But if your process might lead to such a usecase .. it needs refining to limit mutliple writes to the same column/ field value

Comment: @RickJames I have seen both, if I got it right, a column will only be update once, so even if there are four, five transactions to update that column, A in ACID is saying that, the first transaction will have to complete before attending to another? further more, if the first transaction fails, then the rest fails: this make sense because the failed transaction might actually affect/determine the value of the next transaction.
So, I want to guess that these transactions are kind of queued for execution?